# Updating sqlalchemy orm instance in flask session

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

In my flask app, I store an instance of a user object in the session

```py
session["user"] = user #Where user is an object
```

I found out that when updating the object stored in the session directly and commit, the changes are not reflected in the database.

However, I found that when updating the database object directly, the changes are reflected in the database while the session object is unchanged.

If I try a method like

```py
user.username = username
user.password = password
db.commit() #I called my database session 'db', probably not a good idea but not the point
session["user"] = user
```

it throws:

> sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance  is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed

What could be a possible solution to update the database correctly and reflect the changes to the flask session? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the `flask-login` extension or just plain flask?

Comment: Is `session` the database session or a normal dict?

Comment: I'm using plain flask and session in this case is the dictionary for flask-session not the database session

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `{'expire_on_commit': False}` like,

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={

    'expire_on_commit': False

})
```

Comment: you are missing an equals sign here `session_options{`. It should be `session_options = {`